# Difference between two attributes in a class

Tags: python, class

Can you please explain to me what is the difference between the attribute that we put in `def __init__` (`c_name`) and the one we put inside the class (`self.name`)?

```
class human:
    def __init__(self, c_name, c_age):
          print("Creation of Human...")
          self.name = c_name
          self.age = c_age
```

Comment: ```c_name``` would only be accessible during the initialization of the object (only in that function). ```self.name``` would be accessible while the object is alive (in any class function or function where you pass the object, as long as you don't destroy it)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial centre or discussion forum. If you want help with fundamental language concepts - if you need something basic *explained* - it would be better to try somewhere like Reddit or Quora. Stack Overflow is from when you need help making something *work*, basic or otherwise (of course, there are other requirements; please see [ask] for details).

Answer (score 0):

`c_name` is a parameter of the function `__init__` and `__init__` is called whenever a new instance of that class is created. In Python `self` also represents an instance of the class. So here, doing `self.name = c_name` assigns the local value of c_name to the attribute `self.name`. This means it will be accessible for the life of the object instead of just inside the call to `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

First, `c_name` is not an attribute. It's called "parameter".

`self.name` is an instance variable. Because `self` is pointing to our recently created instance and we set the attribute `name` to it.

`c_name` is local to the `__init__` method, so if we don't store it in our instance namespace, we can't have access to it inside another methods or elsewhere outside `__init__`. Just like regular functions:

```
def fn(a):
    a += 1
    
fn(10)

print(a)   # NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: thanx a lot , please what is the difference between attribut and attribut of a class

Comment: @Mohamed A value associated with an object which is referenced by name using dotted expressions. For example, if an object `o` has an attribute `a` it would be referenced as `o.a`. In other words, a variable(?) that is belong to an object. sometime these attributes can be callable as well. we call them methods ! if they are a single value, we say "data attribute".  so A class can have attribtue(class attribute), an instance can have attribute(instance attribute). In python everything is an object ! so everything can have attribute.

Answer (score 0):

### when we use attribute in `__init__` function

- the init function automatically get involved during the the object creation
- anything we create using `self.` refers to the class **attribute**
- according to the question `self.name` is attribute specific to the the object created from class `human`.
- we can access this attribute from anywhere like this

```
a = human("anyname",11)
print (a.name)
```

*output*

`anyname`

when we use a function with some other name